# Squirrel store result in file error SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501

Tags: db2, export, squirrel-sql

When I try to do

```
set schema foo

SELECT COMPANY_NO, COUNTRY_CODE FROM CRED_PROC_COMPANIES
```

And do session -> scripts -> store result of sql in file

it fails with

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, 
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the schema inside the select statement like `SELECT COMPANY_NO, COUNTRY_CODE FROM foo.CRED_PROC_COMPANIES`